# Bundler can't find dependencies url

Tags: ruby, bundler

I always get this error whenever I do anything involving a built in bundler exec.

```
Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
Fetching full source index from http://rubygems.org/
```

I'm not sure where to even begin looking? Thanks.

Comment: Check http://isitup.org/rubygems.org in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency API is currently down

http://status.rubygems.org/

Comment: so it's more or less an intermittent connection issue?